# Recorded file neither saving nor playing in cordova-plugin-media (Error code 1)

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, cordova-media-plugin

I'm using this plugin:  `cordova-plugin-media` with ionic capacitor instead of cordova with command `ionic cap sync`.

My code:

```
audioFile: MediaObject;
constructor(private media: Media, private plt: Platform, private file: File) {}
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.plt.ready()
    .then(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.audioFile = this.media.create(this.file.externalRootDirectory + 'audiofile.mp3');
        this.audioFile.onStatusUpdate.subscribe(status => console.log('status: ', status));
        this.audioFile.onSuccess.subscribe(() => console.log('Action is successful'));
        this.audioFile.onError.subscribe(error => console.log('Error: ', error));
      }, 1000);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('ready error: ', err));
}

record() {
    // When record button clicked
    this.audioFile.startRecord();
}

stop() {
    // When stop button clicked
    this.audioFile.stopRecord();
    this.audioFile.play();
}
```

When I clicked Record btn, `record()` was executed and output was: `Error: 1` and when I stopped recording than the output was `status: 4` and `Action is successful`
I expected to either play the recording or get `audiofile.mp3` in the file manager of my android device but I didn't observed any of it. Can someone help me with this issue?

What I tried:

- I thought that its extension issue so I tried replacing mp3 with 3gp and m4a
- I tried removing `file://` from `file.externalRootDirectory` with slice method - `file.externalRootDirectory.slice(7)`
- Instead of externalRootDirectory I also tried applicationDirectory and externalDataDirectory
- I also submitted my issue on their [github repository](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/issues/301) but I didn't got any response yet
- I tried finding solutions on other communities and stackoverflow itself but problem still exists

Comment: On which device are you testing it? What version of Android or iOS is your device running?

Comment: I'm testing on Android 10

Comment: Added an answer. Please try this solution.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Android 10 uses a new file system](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage)** therefore plugins that have not updated themselves might not read/create files on Android 10.

You need to manually add this line in your manifest file : **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**

1. Open your project in Android Studio and open the AndroidManifest file.
2. In  tag inside your manifest file, add    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
3. Rebuild your project

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Doesn't work on Android 11. I guess these plugins need to release updates and comply with the new file system policies.